# How to calculate the factorial of n using stacks

Tags: c++, stack, factorial

I need to calculate the factorial of n using stacks and the code I made doesn't return any results. I also don't know what pop stack really does ( What it's second parameter is for ) so I just used a random value there. I used `int **x;` because I didn't know what to put here `pop(&mystack,*x);`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
int aux;
int aux1;
int aux2;
int **x;
typedef struct {
    int content[100];
    int top;
} stack;
stack mystack;

int push(stack *somestack,int somevalue)
{
    if (somestack->top+1>=100)
        return 1;
    (*somestack).top++;
    (*somestack).content[(*somestack).top]=somevalue;
    return 0;
}

int pop(stack *somestack, int *oldvalue)
{
    if((*somestack).top==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    *oldvalue=(*somestack).content[(*somestack).top];
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"n=";
    cin>>n;
    push(&mystack,n);
    int direction=1;
    while(mystack.top>=1)
    {
        if((direction==1)&&(mystack.content[mystack.top]>1))
        {
            aux=mystack.content[mystack.top];
            push(&mystack,aux-1);
        }
        else
        {
            if(mystack.content[mystack.top]==1)
            {
                direction=0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(aux1<n)
                {
                    aux1=mystack.content[mystack.top];
                    aux2=aux1*(aux1+1);
                    pop(&mystack,*x);
                    mystack.content[mystack.top]=aux2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<mystack.content[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks as if you have copy/pasted some code and you are looking for advice as to how to debug it. I recommend that you write your own code to accomplish your task, using this code a bit of a guideline. Then, when you are actually getting result, you will likely find the solution on your own. If you get stuck after that, we're here.

Comment: It make sense to move `push`/`pop` free functions into member functions of `stack`.

Answer (score 4):

Stacks have push and pop operations. Push adds a new item to the top of the stack and pop removes the item from the top of the stack and returns it. Some pseudocode for factorial:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    Stack<int> stack;
    stack.push(1);

    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
       stack.push(stack.pop()*i);
    }
    return stack.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the interpreter pattern, and its nothing more than putting the numbers from n..2 in the stack (exclude 1 as it is the base case)

```
package main

import "github.com/ayalaio/utils/stack"

type MathFact struct {
    Content int
}

func (self *MathFact) FactorialFunc() func(int) int {
    return func(j int) int {
        return self.Content * j
    }
}

func main() {
    s := stack.New()

    factorialOf := 6

    curr := factorialOf

    for curr >= 2 {
        s.Add(&MathFact{curr})
        curr--
    }

    // 1 -> base case
    r := 1
    for s.Len() > 0 {
        e := s.Front()
        ff := e.Value.(*MathFact).FactorialFunc()
        r = ff(r)
        s.Remove()
    }
    println(r)
}
```